# Web client works on GlassFish 4, but not on GlassFish 3

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I'm developing some enterprise web site using Java EE 6 technology. My collegue was assigned working on web client and he develops it on his PC using JSF 2.1 and GlassFish 4.0. When I tried running that web client on my PC, which at first had GlassFish 3.1 instaled, it didn't work. Not a single line of xhtml code was rendered on my web browser.

Later on, I installed GlassFish 4 and deployed application on it and look at miracle - it worked! So basicaly, my question is simple: Why does that happend? Why can't I run web client on older version of GlassFish server?

P.S. No error or warning is recorded on server's log when I try to run it on GlassFish 3.1.

Comment: Check the XSD definitions in the various XML files in your deployment.  Be especially careful that the versions used are supported in Glassfish 3 and not only Glassfish 4.

Comment: Are you sure your friend was working with JSF 2.1 and not with JSF 2.2?

Comment: Well, it appears that way. Since he developed web client using latest version of both NetBeans and GlassFish, I assume that he inherently used JSF 2.2. As I've read somwhere on the internet, GlassFish versions prior 4.0 don't support JSF2.2, it needs to be installed manually.